# webdriver-manager update throwing an error "Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found"

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am new to protractor so please go easy on me.

I am facing the below error while running the command:

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy http://proxy.companyname.com:portnumber
```

---

```
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.1.1
[17:33:49] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json 'http://proxy.company.com:port/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases' -H 'host:api.github.com'
[17:33:49] I/downloader - curl -om\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar 'http://proxy.company.com:port/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar' -H 'host:selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
[17:33:49] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists \node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[17:33:49] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
[17:33:49] I/downloader - curl -oC:\Users\731320\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/chromedriver_2.46.zip 'http://proxy.company.com:port/2.46/chromedriver_win32.zip' -H 'host:chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
[17:33:49] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.46.zip

C:\Users\xyx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\node_modules\adm-zip\zipFile.js:66
                        throw Utils.Errors.INVALID_FORMAT;
                        ^
Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found
```

Because of which when I am trying to kickstart the selenium server I am getting error:

```
      Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile 
      C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver- 
       manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
      [17:39:21] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
```

I have also tried to manually place the selenium jar file in the folder, but that didn't work.

Could any one assist me on this?

Comment: This error usually comes when you try to access the files before unzipping. Can you remove the `node_modules` folder and then try installing again.

Comment: I have deleted the node_modules folder and installed everything from the scratch, but I am unable to identify the issue

Comment: Also please remove your company proxy from the stack trace. I can see the proxy link and the port number.

Comment: @demouser123 Thanks.Any other solution?

Comment: Could you try running `webdriver-manager clean` before update this "removes all downloaded driver files from the out_dir"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command from your project folder after `npm i webdriver-manager`.

`node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Nope that didn't work, I was getting the same error.What does the above code do?.I believe that the issue is with drivers are not unzipping and the selenium standalone jar file is corrupt.

Comment: I tried the below command and observed that there is no drivers installed C:\Users\731320>webdriver-manager status
        [10:49:06] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.141.59
        [10:49:06] I/status - chromedriver is not present
       [10:49:06] I/status - geckodriver is not present
       [10:49:06] I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
       [10:49:06] I/status - android-sdk is not present
       [10:49:06] I/status - appium is not present

Comment: before doing the option in the answer,
run your command promt as administrator
run-> `npm i webdriver-manager -g`
then run->`webdriver-manager update`
If you still face the problem do again the answer suggested.

Comment: No, I don't have access for running as admin as I am connected to the company proxy.

Comment: Not working.I think that the proxy is blocking the unzipping of the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The all above may not work if you are connected to an organization network. Please try the following in your terminal
node

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --proxy http://MY_USER@MY_PROXY:8080 --versions.chrome=105.0.5195.52 --verbose
```

or

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --proxy http://MY_USER@MY_PROXY:8080 -
```